# Android EditText input changing as we typing on it(number)

Tags: android

i'm making an app that can calculate payOnloan,prepaid,etc(3 months project from my supervisor, i'm having an intern).But i got stuck at some point.I want to have an EditText where it will automatically change its value, in this case numbers as we input the value.Example:

whene type 1
in EditText output
1
when we type 10
in EditText output
10
when we type 100
in EditText output
100
when we type 1.000
in EditText output
1.000
when we type 10.000
in EditText output
10.000
and so on..(until 1.000.000.000.000)
note:for one EditText,i mean we give the input on it and the output also on the same edittext

is it possible to do this?i've tried almost everything related like number separator or decimal format or currency convert.But none of that works.

i cant attach image file sry about that,

thanks in advance,

Regards,
George

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have an Edit text box and whatever you type inside that it needs to be reflected on some other view? If that is the case, a text watcher is what you are looking for.

Comment: its like automatically add "."(period) each time the input(number)have more than 3 digits,example 1000 >to 1.000 ,1000000 to 1.000.000(it will happening as we typing(in the edit text box)) .Similar to currency format

Comment: You would still need a Text Watcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you define your decimal Format?

Try something like this:

```
DecimalFormat formattedStuff = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,##0");
String receivedStr = yourEditText.getText().toString();
yourEditText.setText(formattedStuff.format(receivedStr));
```

Comment: its not a decimal cause the EditText box could also have any numbers like     ......12345678 to 12.345.678

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html    For example, if the primary grouping interval is 3, and the secondary is 2, then this corresponds to the pattern "#,##,##0", and the number 123456789 is formatted as "12,34,56,789". If a pattern contains multiple grouping separators, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer defines the primary grouping size, and the interval between the last two defines the secondary grouping size. All others are ignored, so "#,##,###,####", "###,###,####" and "##,#,###,####" produce the same result.

Comment: new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,##0");  This would work for non-decimal number types.  If you actually needed the decimals, you could use  new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,##0.##");  Notice the difference in using the comma and the period, they are important.

Comment: Sry, my bad. I thought ### = 000.Yea ### could be any numbers .Thanks

Comment: wait, if i want to use period instead of comma, example #,###,### to #.###.### , will that work?

Comment: No, the DecimalFormat uses commas to separate groups, which will then likely be translated to periods based on your device's default settings.  The period can only be used once.

Comment: i see, then is it possible to translate it on code?

Comment: I don't think so, but as long as your app uses the devices default language, I believe it should format it correctly based on your region.

Comment: how to do that, i'm new with stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, you have an Edit text box and whatever you type inside that it needs to be reflected on some other view? If that is the case, a text watcher is what you are looking for.

Here is an example of text watcher:

```
final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher(){
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            yourView.setText(yourEditText.getText().toString()); 
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Pay attention to: `public void onTextChanged`
However beware of null values!

Check the length of your number in the text watcher on textChange and use the following to add decimals:

```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
  String inputFormated = df.format(yourEditText.getText.toString());
  System.out.println(inputFormated);
```

Comment: is it better to put that on maincode or make a new class to handle it?

Comment: That is your call as I am not aware of your use case. However a Textwatcher carries negligible overhead.

Comment: I'm bad at english.I dont know how to describe it well ,sorry about that. I'm confused myself ...